# PHP autoloader not working

Tags: php, php-5.3

I seem to have some misconceptions on how autoloading works in PHP still, one I simply cannot explain.

I have a class called `glue` which has a `spl_autoload_register` within it's main function, here called `run` like so:

```
class glue{
    public static function run(){
        spl_autoload_register(array('glue','autoload'));
    }
}
```

The autoload function works by loading via the PSR-0 standard and works from absolute paths. This is all tested as working etc. Note that `glue` is not namespaced.

The autoload function covers a namespace called `glue`. Within this namespace I have a error handler called `\glue\ErrorHandler`.

When I trigger an error the `glue` class will autoload `\glue\ErrorHandler` by PSR-0 notation from the root directory as defined by a stored `ROOT` constant. This has been tested as working as well in classes such as `\glue\User` and `\glue\Session`.

So now for the problem. I cause a `Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated` error within `\glue\Validation` and it doesn't seem to run my autoload function.

I can see how it is going into my autoload function for everything but when I call this error in that class it just seems to skip my autoloader and bail out saying it can't find my error handler class.

Normally I would say it is something with my programming but I have tried everything. I cannot explain how, for this one error. What compounds my confusion further is that if I cause a:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_ISSET in /media/server_ws/xxxxxxx/glue/Validation.php on line 47
```

Error it works. It seems to be for that one error it just will not autoload my error handler.

I thought this might be because my `spl_autoload_register` is not being binded to that namespace (since the error handler that works is actually called from within `glue`) and some how, maybe, it is randomly working. So from `\glue\Validation` I called a class I have never looked at: `\glue\util\Crypt` but that works and goes into the autoloader correctly.

When I call this error: `Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated` from within `glue` class it works perfectly.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

#### Edit

As requested here is a brievated version of `Validation.php`:

```
namespace glue;

use glue,
    \glue\Exception,
    \glue\Collection;

class Validation extends \glue\Component{
    private function validateRule($rule){
        // This is the line, notice the pass by reference down there?
        $valid = $validator($field,$field_value,$params,&$this->model) && $valid;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about you give us you Validation.php file ?

Comment: @user1737909 It is a big file but I can put up a simple structure

Comment: @user1737909 Added a cut down example

Comment: I need the lines around line 47

Comment: @user1737909 That was just a random error I made that worked, the one that does not work is displayed above, the pass by reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated` error is thrown during script compilation, and auto-loading is disabled during compilation. It's disabled because the compiler cannot start compiling multiple scripts at the same time (i.e. it is not re-entrant), and auto-loading may load some script, which may require compiling it.

Source: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/76ad52ccc501c02aeb068d2eb4f119ef6f0c2b6a/Zend/zend_execute_API.c#L1058

Comment: That is the thing it does trigger the error handler, it complains that it cannot find my file: `Class 'glue\ErrorHandler' not found in /media/server_ws/xxxx/glue/Validation.php on line 75` For some reason it won't run my autoloader when it comes to throw that error from that class

Comment: is the autoloader registered at the time the file with a `call-time pass-by-ref` is parsed ?

Comment: Nah, it is registered way back, the program runs about half of itself first. I get all that half of output too. So `glue::run()` is called and then some time later, `$d=new \glue\Validation(); $d->validateRule();`

Comment: Updating answer explaining why the autoloader is not used in this case

Comment: How come it works if I cause this error in the `glue` class then but it doesn't work in the `\glue\Validator` class?

Comment: is it possible that the ErrorHandle class is already loaded when you cause the error in the glue class ?

Comment: I think this might be it, I did some more testing, it bails out before instantiating the class which means it bails upon parsing the php as you state, so the more I test the more it seems this is the root cause. I also think the reason why it works in my glue class is because all of those methods are static, whereas validation is all dynamic, as such the change to way static binding occured in PHP to take care of late static binding probably means this oddly works